# RewriteEngine - forcing new friendly URLs causes too many redirections

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This rule translates URLs like
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=about to friendly URLs like http://www.example.com/about

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)?$     index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

It's working well. But, currently old URLs (like http://www.example.com/index.php?page=about) are indexed in google. So, in addition to that rule I need to redirect all old URLs (like http://www.example.com/index.php?page=about) to new friendly URLs (like http://www,example.com/about) so when visitor old URL he gets redirected to friendly URL. I wrote that rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.pl/%1? [NC,R=301,L]
```

and it redirects to new URL but instead of showing a website content, it throws an error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting too many redirect error because of your internal rewriteRules,as  they internaly forward the request to the same location after first rewrite iteration, to fix this , add the following at top of your htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

or you can match against %{THE_REQUEST} instead of %{QUERY_STRING} to avoid rewrite loop/too many redirect error

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
```